# How can I use XMPP for chat process with PHP

Tags: php, xmpp

I want to integrate a chat option in my website, but I am not getting the proper flow. How to make it possible?

I have Registered the user on Xmpp, now I have to apply one-to-one chat in php. Please guide me.

Comment: Hi i want to integrate chat functionality using xmpp(openfire) in php

Comment: Have you registered your user to Openfire server from PHP backend? Would you like to implement XMPP features on backend? Why not in the frontend (HTML/JS) ?

Comment: Yes i have registered users on openfire & yes it is possible but this application is already developed in Android using Xmpp so we have to sysnchronize web as well as in device side.

Comment: What does you mean with "web"? It's a web client?

Comment: No I have to integrate in my website like facebook chatting.

Comment: So if I understand it is like a web widget and it could be done on the client side: see for example https://conversejs.org/

Comment: Hi beaver its very nice demo for chatting infact its a best.But how i will register user on my private domain it is working if i register user on public domains.

Comment: It can be integrated with your own XMPP server (Openfire, Ejabberd, ...) and so your own domain (see https://conversejs.org/docs/html/setup.html#an-xmpp-server).

Answer (score 1):

You can add chat features to your website using an [**XMPP library for HTML/JS**](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html) or integrating an already-done [**XMPP client**](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.html).

If you need a chat **widget** you could see for example [**conversejs.org**](https://conversejs.org). It can be integrated with your own XMPP server (Openfire, Ejabberd, ...) and so your own domain (see https://conversejs.org/docs/html/setup.html#an-xmpp-server).

Otherwise  if you prefer a complete chat **webclient** check for example [**Candy**](https://candy-chat.github.io/candy/). Also Candy can be used with your specific XMPP server (see https://github.com/candy-chat/candy/wiki/Installing-a-XMPP-server).

Finally if you want to develop your own web chat feature (widget or app) you could rely on a simple JS library such as **[Strophe.js](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiq5Jyait7KAhWDdQ8KHQIeArMQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstrophe.im%2Fstrophejs%2F&usg=AFQjCNHtaFs82SHlXMITaWSs5dvhRKk8Mw&sig2=htCVxpRbqvel6-dcWZYliQ)**.